# Merging two threads in a MOSS 2007 Discussion Board

Tags: 2007, administration, discussion-board

I have an email-enabled discussion board on a MOSS site which is working fine except that sometimes people will be using obscure email clients that don't reply with all headers or otherwise operating in such a way that a reply to one thread appears as the start of a new one.

Is there any way to combine the two threads in this circumstance?

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any out-of-the box solutions for merging threads, but if you are going to achieve this programatically you have a couple of useful functions in the SPUtility class: [SPUtility.CreateNewDiscussion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms474815%28v=office.12%29.aspx) and [SPUtility.CreateNewDiscussionReply](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility.createnewdiscussionreply%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

It can be tricky working with discussions programatically, but these methods helps a lot.